# Issue with a foreach with key

Tags: php, foreach

I need to extract some datas from my foreach but no way .

**This is my foreach**

```
$res = $pdo->getLesProduits();
$data = array( 'res'=> array());
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    $data['res'][$key] =  $value;
}
```

**This is my query**

```
public function getLesProduits(){
$req = "select * from produit";
$res = PdoGR::$monPdo->query($req);
$lesLignes = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $lesLignes;
}
```

**And this is var_dump($data)**

[image: var_dump($data)]

But i need, for example to get all 'reference' or all 'designation', but when i execute this :

```
echo $res['designation'];
```

I see only one line ..

UPDATE :

```
if(isset($_POST['referenceProduit'])){
    $res = $pdo->getLesProduits();
    $data = array( 'res'=> array());
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        //$data['res'][$key] =  $value;
        $designations = array_column($res['res'], 'designation');
        $unique_designations = array_unique(array_column($res['res'], 'designation'));
        $designations = array_values(array_filter($array['res'], function($a) use($_POST['referenceProduit']){
        return $a['reference'] == $reference;}))[0];
    }
    $data['produit'] =  '       
        <label for="designation" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Désignation</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation" value="'. $a['reference'] .'" readonly>
        </div>
        <label for="prix" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Prix </label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="prix" id="prix" value="'. $value['prix'] .'" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">€</span>
        </div>
        ';
}
```

Comment: because `'res'` is a array itself. using an array in a string context turns it into the literal word `Array`, not the array's contents. `echo $arr['res'][2]['reference'] -> C714`

Comment: ...not sure what your actual question / issue is. `$res` looks like it's a standard zero indexed array so I wouldn't expect `$res['designation']` to work at all.